# What is the correct way to extend BrightcovePlayer in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, brightcove

I am trying to play a sample video using Brightcove Player. The [documentation](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-android/getting-started/brightcoveplayer.html) suggests that to implement basic lifecycle callbacks for the player one should extend BrightcovePlayer instead of a simple activity. Here's how I am extending it:

```
public class BrightCoveActivity extends BrightcovePlayer {

private static final String BC_TOKEN = "<using a valid token here>";
private String mVideoId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bright_cove);
    final BrightcoveVideoView brightcoveVideoView = (BrightcoveVideoView) findViewById(R.id.brightcove_video_view);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Catalog catalog = new Catalog(BC_TOKEN);

    mVideoId = "<using a valid video ID here";

    MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
    brightcoveVideoView.setMediaController(controller);

    catalog.findVideoByID(mVideoId, new VideoListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            throw new RuntimeException(error);

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideo(Video video) {
            brightcoveVideoView.add(video);
            brightcoveVideoView.start();
        }
    });


}
```

}

However I keep getting this `IllegalStateException` when I try to run the app:

```
09-09 17:01:51.988: E/AndroidRuntime(21607): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: brightcoveVideoView needs to be wired up to the layout.
09-09 17:01:51.988: E/AndroidRuntime(21607):    at com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcovePlayer.onCreate(BrightcovePlayer.java:180)
```

This stack trace eventually points to the `super.OnCreate()` method. It does not make a difference whether I call the super-class method before or after I "wire up" the BrightcoveVideoView.

I am using:

1. A **custom layout** with BrightCoveVideoView at this point with no other views except the videoView inside a Relative Layout.
2. **Eclipse** for development (constrained to do so, can't use Android Studio). I have included the legacy .jar file as a library (the project runs fine if I do this in a simple Activity and not a BrightcovePlayer activity).
3. **Brightcove SDK 4.5** for Android.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the media controller before the super.onCreate() method.

```
final BrightcoveVideoView brightcoveVideoView = (BrightcoveVideoView)findViewById(R.id.brightcove_video_view);
MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
brightcoveVideoView.setMediaController(controller);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```